# PHP - strpos() on UTF8-encoded json?

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I have the JSON-output `Kirchhellener Stra\u00dfe`.. the `\u00df` is a UTF8-encoded german letter `ß`..I want to search the output for the word `Straße` and replace it, but I can't figure out how?

```
$street = json_decode($bit->long_name); // here the `Kirchhellener Stra\u00dfe` is put into $street

$check_strasse1 = strpos($street, 'Straße');
$check_strasse2 = strpos($street, 'Stra\u00dfe');

if($check_strasse1 !== false || $check_strasse2 !== false) {    
    echo "oki";             
    $street = str_replace('Strasse', 'Str.', $street);
    $street = str_replace('Stra\u00dfe', 'Str.', $street);
} else {    
    echo "nope";        
}
```

How can I detect it the `$street` has `Straße` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with UTF-8 encoded strings in PHP, you must use `mbstring` extension. In this case, the function you're looking for is `mb_strpos()`.

Or, in this case, you can just use `preg_replace()`:

```
preg_replace('/Straße/u', 'Str.', $street);
```

The `u` modifier ensures that UTF-8 encoding is used when matching the string. You don't need to check if the string is present, because if it's not, it will not be replaced. You can also skip the `\u00df` variant, as `json_decode()` will convert this literal into the proper UTF-8 character.

Comment: dude!.. thank you very much!! :) . i have spend the whole day on this yesterday..  tanks a lot!! :)